# Difficulty to combine the use of base constructors and nonstatic fields

Tags: c#, constructor

I was tackled by this issue for too many times so i decided to share and see what you guys think, lets look at the following (dumb) exemple:

```
public delegate void ToRun();
class Runner {
    ToRun tr;
    public Runner(ToRun f) {
        tr=f;
    }
    public void run() {
        tr();
    }
}
class CountingRunner : Runner {
    ToRun tr;
    int i;
    public CountingRunner(ToRun f) : base(f+=inc) {
        i=0;
    }
    private static void inc() {
        i++; //COMPILATION ERROR - i is not (and logically cannot be) static!
    }
}
```

well, what i want to ask is:

**Q1**: why do base() parms have to be static?

**Q2**: what if, as in my exemple, we want to combine nonstatic fields or methods with the call to the base constructor? what is the most OOP way to do that?

**Note** : try not to give bandaid solutions like "just dont use the base c'tor", cause there might be more complex situation where using base is unavoidable, so im looking for a reasonable well designed solution for this.

Thanks!

**Update**:
my exemple was too easy to crack,therefore i feel like i havent learned enough, so lets try to give another (pretty dumb still) exemple:

```
public delegate int HashFunc<E>(E e);
public interface HashTable<E> {
    void insert(E e);
    bool isMember(E e);
} 
class HashArray<E> : HashTable<E> where E : IComparable<E> {
    private E[] a;
    private bool[] taken;
    public readonly int n;
    public int size {
        get { return n; }
    }
    HashFunc<E> hash;
    public HashArray(int m , HashFunc<E> hash ) {
        n=2*m;
        a=new E[n];
        taken=new bool[n];
        for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) taken[i]=false;
        this.hash=hash;
    }
    public void insert(E e) {
        int index=hash(e),i;
        for (i=index ; i<n && taken[i]!=false ; ++i) ;
        if (i>=n)
            for (i=0 ; i<index && taken[i]!=false ; ++i) ;
        if (i>=index) return;
        taken[i]=true;
        a[i]=e;
    }
    public bool isMember(E e) {
        int i=hash(e);
        for ( ; i<n && taken[i]!=false && a[i].CompareTo(e)!=0 ; ++i );
        if (i>=n || taken[i]==false) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
class HashArrayInt : HashArray<int> {
    public HashArrayInt(int n) : base (n,HashFunc) {
    }
    public static int HashFunc(int i) {
        return (i%n);// n is a non static field, every hash table has its own size!
    }
}
```

in this exemple we are giving some weird implementation for an hash table where the hash function is unknown, and a special class for hash table of ints with predefined hash function, notice that here again we need to combine the non static size of the hashtable n and base c'tor...

Comment: You can make the constructors private and have a static `Create` method to act as a constructor, but you will have more power about how things work from there.

Comment: Just make n a parameter to the hash function?

Comment: yeah thats what i wanted to do, but the delegate was given by the instructor, so we can not change it. also, who said there must be a connection between the hash function and the hash size? so changing the hash delegate might force definning n where it is redundant...

Comment: Well for starters your has function is not really i%n.  It's just i.

Comment: n is a private member variable of the base class.  It can't be part of the hashing function a base class provides because it isn't accessible (and should not be) to the base classes.  I added an edit to my answer.

Comment: my bad, changed it to protected

Comment: well its just for the exemple, but aight how about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
class Runner {
    protected event Action _toRun;

    public Runner() {
    }
    public void Run() {
        var r = _toRun;
        if (r != null)
           _toRun();
    }


}

class CountingRunner : Runner {

    int i;
    public CountingRunner(Action f) : base() {
        _toRun += f;
    }
    public void inc() {
        i++;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For your particular example with hash tables, this problem is solved by the design of the language.  Just call GetHashCode() on the elements of your hashtable to determine their hashcode.  You don't need implementations to pass a hashing function.

To answer your more general question of "How should I send functions manipulating instance data to the base class," you should either capture your instance variables in a lambda expression and send that to the base class, or consider a design in which the base class doesn't need access to the instance functions of its derived classes.  I would go with the latter :)

One such design would be to have the function a pure virtual call in the base class.  That would require derived classes to implement the virtual call in order to be instantiated.  So here you would have a `abstract int GetHashCode(E item)` function in the base class, and just override it in your subclasses.  Again, in this specific case the language does this for you with the virtual `GetHashCode()` function defined for all types.

Here is a non-abstract example (derived classes aren't *required* to override the hashing function).

```
class HashArray<E> : HashTable<E> where E : IComparable<E> {
    private E[] a;
    private bool[] taken;
    public readonly int n;
    public int size {
        get { return n; }
    }

    public HashArray(int m) {
        n=2*m;
        a=new E[n];
        taken=new bool[n];
        for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) taken[i]=false;

    }
    public void insert(E e) {
        int index= GetSpecialHashCode(e)%n;
        int i;
        for (i=index ; i<n && taken[i]!=false ; ++i) ;
        if (i>=n)
            for (i=0 ; i<index && taken[i]!=false ; ++i) ;
        if (i>=index) return;
        taken[i]=true;
        a[i]=e;
    }
    public bool isMember(E e) {
        int i= GetSpecialHashCode(e)%n;
        for ( ; i<n && taken[i]!=false && a[i].CompareTo(e)!=0 ; ++i );
        if (i>=n || taken[i]==false) return false;
        return true;
    }

    protected virtual int GetSpecialHashCode(E item) {
        return item.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

So you get a default hashcode generating function, but derived classes are also welcome to supply their own.

Comment: that wouldnt work because then only int hash table would be instantiable

Comment: Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

> Q1: why do base() parms have to be static?

They must be static because the instance hasn't been defined at the time of the constructor call (that definition was "in progress").

> Q2: what if, as in my exemple, we want to combine nonstatic fields or methods with the call to the base constructor? what is the most OOP way to do that?

To OOP-way would is just simple method overrides.

```
class Runner
{
    ToRun tr;
    public Runner(ToRun f) 
    {
        tr=f;
    }

    public virtual void Run()
    {
        tr();
    }
}

class CountingRunner : Runner {
    int i;
    public CountingRunner(ToRun f) : base(f) {
        i=0;
    }
    public override void Run() {
        i++; 
        base.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for correct ansewr, but remove `ToRun tr` member from `CountingRunner`

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk It is needed in `Runner`... You're saving the `ToRun` in a member so you can call it whenever someone invokes your `Run` method.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk:  It still has meaning in `Runner` as an injected action.

Comment: Btw this is actually not good OOP because you are requiring the derived class to call the base class function.  Very bad design.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk why is this bad design?

Comment: It is a common anti-pattern (a pattern that is unhelpful or harmful).   

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super

Answer (score 1):

Regarding both **Q1** and **Q2**, it's not that the parameters must be static, but rather the parameters must be accessible at the time they are invoked.

And base constructors are invoked prior to the local constructor, which is why you can't use `this` members as parameter for example, and why you shouldn't invoke virtual calls.

Not totally sure what the ultimate goal of that would be, but it does resemble a [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the decorator pattern, which might be of use for the OP in his actual case.

Answer (score 1):

For your last example, I think this could work:

```
class HashArrayInt : HashArray<int> {
    public HashArrayInt(int n) : base (n,i => HashFunc(i,n)) {
    }
    private static int HashFunc(int i, int n) {
        return (i%n);// n is a non static field, every hash table has its own size!
    }
}
```

If not, you can do this:

```
class HashFuncProvider {
    private int n;
    public HashFuncProvider(int n){
         this.n = n;
    }

    public int HashFunc(int i) {
        return (i%n);
    }
}


class HashArrayInt : HashArray<int> {
    public HashArrayInt(int n) : base (n, new HashFuncProvider(n).HashFunc) {
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not compile.  HashFunc is private, hence inaccessible to HashArrayInt.